# Linear ODE with constants

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

> $$\frac{dc}{dt}=a-bc$$ where $a,b$ are constants
>
> a. Find the solution if at $t=0$, $c=k$
>
> b.Prove that for all k $\lim_{t \to \infty}c(t)=\frac{a}{b}$

Finding the homogeneous solution

$$c_{h}:\frac{dc}{dt}+bc=0$$

$$c_{h}:c=\frac{e^t}{k}$$ where $k=\frac{1}{e^b}$

Variation of Parameters:

$$c_{p}=\frac{e^t}{k(t)}$$

$$c'_{p}=\frac{e^tk(t)-k'(x)e^t}{[k(t)]^2}$$

substitution in the original ODE:

$$\frac{e^tk(t)-k'(x)e^t}{[k(t)]^2}=a-\frac{be^t}{k(t)}$$

$$\frac{e^tk(t)-k'(x)e^t+be^tk(t)}{[k(t)]^2}=a$$

How should I continue from here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hint. You already established that the homogeneous solution is $c_h(t)=Ce^{-bt}$ (not $e^{t}\cdot e^b$) with $C\in\mathbb{R}$. 
What you need now is a particular solution $c_p(t)$.

Note that this linear ODE has a solution which is identically constant. Are you able to find it?

P.S. If you prefer to use the method of Variation of Parameters then let $c_p(t)=k(t)e^{-bt}$. Then
$$a=c_p'(t)+bc_p(t)=k'(t)e^{-bt}-bk(t)e^{-bt}+bk(t)e^{-bt}=k'(t)e^{-bt}\Rightarrow k'(t)=ae^{bt}$$
Hence $k(t)=\frac{a}{b}e^{bt}$ which implies that $c_p(t)=\frac{a}{b}$.

Comment: I know that in the last equation I need to find out $k(t)$ and the expressions of $k(t)$ in the equation usually cancel out

Comment: Your homogeneous solution is wrong and the Variation of Parameters depends on that result. Use $c_p(t)=k(t)e^{-bt}$ .

Comment: @gbox See my P.S. Is it clear now?

Comment: Yes, I forgot the integration constant, but what about it in $k(t)=\frac{a}{b}e^{bt}+c$? why didnt you add it in $k(x)$?

Comment: You don't need the costant. You need A particular solution so you can take the constant as zero.